# C# WPF MouseEnter and MouseLeave on Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, mouseevent, eventhandler

I made 2 MouseEvents, they working, but the problem, that they working not like i have expected. I need these 2 events to be active when my mouse pointer is right in Grid Space, but now they working only if the pointer is on any Line.

my code:

```
            // Grid 3 Rows.
        Grid grid_Edit = new Grid();
        Grid.SetRow(grid_Edit, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(grid_Edit, 1);
        RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition();
        RowDefinition rowDef3 = new RowDefinition();
        grid_Edit.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);
        grid_Edit.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);
        grid_Edit.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef3);
        grid_Edit.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        grid_Edit.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        grid_Edit.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
        grid_Edit.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(gridEdit_MouseEnter);
        grid_Edit.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(gridEdit_MouseLeave);
        mainWindow_ref.Children.Add(grid_Edit);

        // 3 lines
        line1.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        line1.X1 = 1;
        line1.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        Grid.SetRow(line1, 0);
        line1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        line2.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        line2.X1 = 1;
        line2.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        Grid.SetRow(line2, 1);
        line2.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        line3.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        line3.X1 = 1;
        line3.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        Grid.SetRow(line3, 2);
        line3.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        // add lines to grid_Edit
        grid_Edit.Children.Add(line1);
        grid_Edit.Children.Add(line2);
        grid_Edit.Children.Add(line3);



    private static void gridEdit_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        line1.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        line2.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        line3.Stroke = Brushes.White;
    }

    private static void gridEdit_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        line1.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line2.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        line3.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the background color of your Grid to Transparent, this will allow the Grid to capture the mouse events.